# tikz matrix as legend does not work with trim axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-matrix

I am using the tikz-library matrix to create a legend for a plot with two y-axes.
When I add "trim axis right" to the code the legend is stretched to the right.
How can I prevent this?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]

\begin{axis}[%
scale only axis,
hide x axis, 
ylabel={y2},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=right
]

\addplot {ln(x)};
\label{pgfplots:Plot1}
\addplot {ln(x)};
\label{pgfplots:Plot2}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
scale only axis,
xlabel={x},
ylabel={y1},
]
\addplot {ln(x)}; 
\label{pgfplots:Plot3}

\addplot {ln(x)}; 
\label{pgfplots:Plot4}

\addplot {ln(x)}; 
\label{pgfplots:Plot5}

\addplot {ln(x)}; 
\label{pgfplots:Plot6}


\end{axis}

\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=north west,
    fill=white,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.3em,
    column sep = 0.3em,
    node font=\scriptsize,
    align=left,
    column 1/.style={nodes={anchor=center}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={anchor=west}},
    column 3/.style={nodes={anchor=center}},
    column 4/.style={nodes={anchor=west}},
    draw
  ]
  at (current axis.north west){
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot1}& Text1 & \ref{pgfplots:Plot4}& Text4\\
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot2}& Text2 & \ref{pgfplots:Plot5}& Text5\\
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot3}& LongerText & \ref{pgfplots:Plot6}& LongerText\\};


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Another problem is that the colored lines in the legend are a bit above the middle of the text height of the corresponding label. If

```
column 1/.style={nodes={anchor=center}},
column 2/.style={nodes={anchor=west}},
column 3/.style={nodes={anchor=center}},
column 4/.style={nodes={anchor=west}},
```

is removed then they are in the middle but the plot labels are not centered anymore.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you make your example smaller? For example, remove everything in your example that is not related to the bug (say, all the text, the colours, the irrelevant plots etc.).

Comment: I have shortened the code a little now. I left the plots in because I need them to show the second problem concerning the vertical shift of the colored lines by the column style commands.

Comment: Why not use the `legend entries` key?

Comment: Because the problem also occurs with groupplot (when "trim axis group right/left is used") and I want to use a single legend for all plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only as a workaround: Set the `text width` option for the nodes containing the colored lines in the legend:

```
column 1/.style={nodes={align=center,text width=.6cm}},
column 2/.style={nodes={anchor=base west}},
column 3/.style={nodes={align=center,text width=.6cm}},
column 4/.style={nodes={anchor=base west}},
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    hide x axis,
    ylabel={y2},
    axis x line*=bottom,axis y line*=right
  ]
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot1}
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot2}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    xlabel={x},ylabel={y1},
  ]
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot3}
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot4}
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot5}
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot6}
\end{axis}
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=north west,
    fill=white,draw,
    inner sep=0.3em,
    %column sep = 0.3em,
    node font=\scriptsize,
    column 1/.style={nodes={align=center,text width=.6cm}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={anchor=base west}},
    column 3/.style={nodes={align=center,text width=.6cm}},
    column 4/.style={nodes={anchor=base west}},
  ]
  at (current axis.north west){
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot1}& Text1 & \ref{pgfplots:Plot4}& Text4\\
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot2}& Text2 & \ref{pgfplots:Plot5}& Text5\\
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot3}& LongerText & \ref{pgfplots:Plot6}& LongerText\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is another suggestion which may be incompatible with image externalization: Remove `trim axis left, trim axis right` and insert

```
\pgfresetboundingbox% resets the bounding box
\useasboundingbox(current axis.below south west)
  rectangle (current axis.above north east);% defines a new one
```

after the second plot. I have inserted a orange rectangle in the following picture to show the resulting bounding box.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    hide x axis,
    ylabel={y2},
    axis x line*=bottom,axis y line*=right
  ]
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot1}
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot2}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    xlabel={x},ylabel={y1},
  ]
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot3}
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot4}
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot5}
  \addplot {ln(x)};\label{pgfplots:Plot6}
\end{axis}
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=north west,
    fill=white,draw,
    inner sep=0.3em,
    %column sep = 0.3em,
    node font=\scriptsize,
    column 1/.style={nodes={align=center}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={anchor=base west}},
    column 3/.style={nodes={align=center}},
    column 4/.style={nodes={anchor=base west}},
  ]
  at (current axis.north west){
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot1}& Text1 & \ref{pgfplots:Plot4}& Text4\\
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot2}& Text2 & \ref{pgfplots:Plot5}& Text5\\
    \ref{pgfplots:Plot3}& LongerText & \ref{pgfplots:Plot6}& LongerText\\};
\pgfresetboundingbox% resets the bounding box
\useasboundingbox(current axis.below south west)
  rectangle (current axis.above north east);% defines a new one
% to show the resulting bounding box
\draw[orange,very thick](current bounding box.south west)
  rectangle(current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```